# How to access the value of a radio button thats grouped by a fieldset that's inside a form, using them "name" property in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm not using frameworks. I have a form, and inside of it I have a fieldset that groups a  radio button.
I've obtained the form element in front-end Javascript, and now, i want to know witch of radio buttons is checked. FOr this, I'm trying to use the fieldset and radio button's names. But I get an undefined:

```js
       const formElement = document.getElementById('form-cad-usuario')

        formElement.onsubmit = e => {
            e.preventDefault()
            const formUser = e.target
            console.log(formUser.generos.checked)   //Returns undefined
            console.log("geneto: "+formUser.generos.genero.checked) //Returns undefined
          }
```

```html
<form method="dialog" class="formulario" id="form-cad-usuario">
                <fieldset name="generos">
                    <legend>Gênero </legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="genero" value="Feminino"> Feminino
                    <input type="radio" name="genero" value="Masculino"> Masculino
                    <input type="radio" name="genero" value="Outros"> Outros
                </fieldset>
                <button type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
</form>
```

I thought I could navigate through the form using it's childs "name" properties. So what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

you can use filter and map to get the value of the checked input.

```js
const formElement = document.getElementById("form-cad-usuario");

formElement.onsubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formUser = e.target;
  
  const checkedInput = [...formUser.elements]
    .filter((input) => input.checked) // Here you filter the inputs to get the checked value
    .map((input) => input.checked); // here you get the checked input value
  
  console.log(checkedInput);
};
```

```html
<form method="dialog" class="formulario" id="form-cad-usuario">
  <fieldset name="generos">
    <legend>Gênero </legend>
    <input type="radio" name="genero" value="Feminino"> Feminino
    <input type="radio" name="genero" value="Masculino"> Masculino
    <input type="radio" name="genero" value="Outros"> Outros
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the "fieldset" tag doesn't have a "name" attribute. But, I can navigate to the radio button directly from the form using the radio "name" only, and get the value of the checked one, through "value" attribute. So I've solved like this:

console.log(formUser.genero.value) //Prints the radio selected